# ezproxy PHP 5.3.3 PDO is auto replacing database values

Tags: php, pdo, host

Lets say my site is http://www.example.com.
Schools use ezproxy to connect to my site. The url becomes http://www.example.com.schoo.org.

I have table with values like http://www.example.com/page1.php.

But when I do a fetch on this table, the returned values are http://www.example.com.schoo.org/page1.php.

I am totally confused right now, why is PDO changing DB values?

Am i missing something?

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM sometable');
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Edit: Turns out EZProxy changes all text which looks like url. Not just links. Thanks @chris85

Comment: How do you expect anyone to answer this question without seeing any code?

Comment: please post the code where you fetch the data.  also, are you echo'ing the returned result to see the changed value?

Comment: Have you got an htaccess file in use?

Comment: @chris85 sounds interesting. Instead of printing it, will try writing it to a file on the server.

Comment: @chris85 you were right. The dump file on server had the correct values, but the response had changed values. But now I have a problem where that variable is supposed to be Google oAuth redirect URL and it is being changed. Any idea how to work around that?
Also, can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Darren Usually when people post a question on Stack Overflow, they have spent hours debugging, searching for solutions and then as a final resort submit a question. When somebody is exhausted debugging a production issue on a Sunday, its normal for somebody to miss basic info.

Comment: I've posted that as an answer. You might need to tell the ezproxy not to re-write the oauth links. I recommend talking with the OCLC about that, their support is pretty quick to reply. https://www.oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy.en.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxies don't have access to your drivers, our source code. They modify the generated content of the site for the users. Here's a quote from the ezproxy's FAQ page:

> The proxy rewrites the pages content. Proxying (in General) is possible because EZproxy acts like a simple web browser and faces the database. EZproxy then takes apart the whole html document and rewrites it so all the database links go back to EZproxy.

-http://oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/faq.en.html

In my experience they are used by institutions so students can get access to content the institution subscribes to. This is required because the access in granted via IP authentication which their home/work networks wouldn't match up to.

So pretty much the request goes like this (I bet google has an image for this too).

The browser make a request to the ezproxy server. The proxy then makes a request to the main website. The website processes and sees the request as being from the proxy and send it its content. Ezproxy then modifies that content so the URLs point to its locations rather than to the main sites location and sends it back to the browser/client.